Given a table with a value z and polar coordinates (r, phi), how can I use matplotlib to plot these values on a polar grid?
I have a pandas dataframe with three columns. The first column is value z, and the other two columns are polar coordinates (r and phi, respectively, where phi is assumed degrees). r and phi are whole numbers such that they range r=[0,1,2...N] and phi=[0,1,2...360].
I would like to create a polar plot for the value, z, based on the coordinates provided. To do this, I would think a contour plot would be the solution. I first realized the contour function needs a mesh grid, so I used that instead of taking the columns from my df. Still, when I try using this code:
phi_range = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 1))
r_range = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

r, theta = np.meshgrid(phi_range, r_range)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(theta, r, z)

I get the error Input z must be 2D, not 1D. This makes sense to me. In polar plots I have done in the past, I have usually been able to pass the meshgrid through a function to generate the value z. In this case, however, I have to use the dataset I have been given.
Is there a way to still make this type of plot?

While testing your code, I have noticed that phi_range evaluates to an array of one single element [0.] (due to the third argument num, see doc). I do not believe it is the problem, but also I guess it not making your test code to work as you expect

@Luca Yes, sorry, thanks for catching that. The new error is not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1), which also aligns with the z value not being tied to the meshgrid.

Despite not very efficient, you could create a len(phi_range) × len(r_range) empty array and use the values from the dataframe to populate it.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set random seed for reproducibility
SEED = 123
np.random.seed(123)

# Create sample df
ROWS, COLS = (500, 3)
R_MAX = 10
z = np.random.rand(ROWS)
r = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = R_MAX+1, size = ROWS)
phi = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 360+1, size = ROWS)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((z, r, phi)).T, columns = ['z', 'r', 'phi'])

# Define the domain
phi_range = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 360 + 1))
r_range = np.arange(0, R_MAX+1, 1)

# Create an empty matrix of z values covering the whole domain
z = np.zeros((len(phi_range), len(r_range)))
# Use fancy indexing to assign z-values
z[df.loc[:,'phi'].values.astype(np.int64),df.loc[:,'r'].values.astype(np.int64)] = df.loc[:,'z']

# Draw the contour plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.contourf(phi_range, r_range, z.T)
plt.show()

Below you can see what I get. It makes no sense at all as the data are randomly generated, but it shows you a way to get the contour plot from the df you described.

If this is not what you are looking for, you should edit your post to make the code a MWE, possibly including (part of) your data.
